# Unsure how to use FFT data for spectrum analyzer

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm trying to create a home made spectrum analyzer with 8 strips of LED's.

The part i'm struggling with is performing the FFT and understanding how to use the results.

So far this is what I have:

```
import opc
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys
import numpy
import math

CHUNK = 1024

# Gets the pitch from the audio
def pitch(signal):
  # NOT SURE IF ANY OF THIS IS CORRECT
  signal = numpy.fromstring(signal, 'Int16');
  print "signal = ", signal

  testing = numpy.fft.fft(signal)
  print "testing = ", testing

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
RATE = wf.getframerate()
p = pyaudio.PyAudio() # Instantiate PyAudio

# Open Stream
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

# Read data
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# Play Stream
while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
    frequency = pitch(data)
    print "%f frequency" %frequency
```

I'm struggling with what to do in the `pitch` method. I know i need to perform FFT on the data that is passed in, but am really unsure how to do it.

Also should be using [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html#numpy.fft.fftfreq) function?

Comment: What are you unsure about? Look at the docs for the two functions.  Did you see the example on the docs page for numpy.fft.fftfreq?   http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm is a good resource.

Comment: The example on this page shows an array of length 8. How did they get that length of 8? My chunk size is 1024 and 2 channels so my array length is 2048. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fftfreq.html#scipy.fftpack.fftfreq

Comment: I would treat the two channels separately.  `np.fft.fft()` will return an array of complex values the same length as its input - each value represents a frequency, the absolute value of the complex number is the magnitude of that frequency, the complex component of the value is its phase shift. `np.fft.fftfreq()` returns an array with the actual frequencies the values from the fourier transform returned.  If you wanted to plot the spectrum `np.absolute(np.fft.fft(signal))` would be the ordinate (y values) and `np.fft.fftfreq(...)` would be the abscissa (x).

Comment: @wwii I somewhat understand what your saying. How would I treat the two channels separately? And if I want to create a spectrum analyzer with 8 bands, how can I do that with a chunk of 1024? If i lower the chunk size to 8, the program runs way too slow.

Comment: The major problem with giving advice is we don't know what your expected output would be.  What do you want those 8 LED strips to do?

Comment: Ambiance light required(best idea) an `MCU` for fast signal processing. OS got more latency if haven't additional hardware(EMBED ON PCI/PCI-E). Dump sound output data calculate peaks(on eight channel) and send to communication port, all will be cool if got synchronization !

Answer (score 4):

Because of the way np.fft.fft works, if you use 1024 data points you will get values for 512 frequencies (plus a value zero Hz, *DC offset*). If you only want 8 frequencies you have to feed it 16 data points.

You might be able to do what you want by down sampling by a factor of 64 - then 16 down sampled points would be *time-equivalent* to 1024 original points.  I've never explored this so I don't know what this entails or what the pitfalls might be.

You're going to have to do some learning - [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm) really is an excellant resource, at least it was for me.

Keep in mind that for an audio cd .wav file the sample frequency is 44100 Hz - a 1024 sample chunk is only 23 mS of the *sound*.

[scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html#scipy.io.wavfile.read) makes getting the data easy.

```
samp_rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)
```

`data` is a 2-d numpy array with one channel in in column zero, data[:,0], and the other in column 1, data[:,1]

Matplotlib's [specgram](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=specgram#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram) and psd functions can give you the data you want. A graphing analog to what you are trying to do would be.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile
samp_rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(data[:1024,0], NFFT = 16, noverlap = 0, Fs = samp_rate)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Since you aren't doing any plotting just use [matplolib.mlab.specgram](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html?highlight=specgram#matplotlib.mlab.specgram).

```
Pxx, freqs, t = matplolib.mlab.specgram(data[:1024,0], NFFT = 16, noverlap = 0, Fs = samp_rate)
```

Its return values (*Pxx*, *freqs*, *t*) are

```
     - *Pxx*: 2-D array, columns are the periodograms of successive segments

     - *freqs*: 1-D array of frequencies corresponding to the rows in Pxx

     - *t*: 1-D array of times corresponding to midpoints of segments.
```

`Pxx[1:, 0]` would be the values for the frequencies for T0, `Pxx[1:, 1]` for T1, `Pxx[1:, 2]` for T2, ... This is what you would feed to your display. You don't use `Pxx[0, :]` because it is for 0 Hz.

power spectral density - [matplotlib.mlab.psd()](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html?highlight=specgram#matplotlib.mlab.psd)

---

Maybe another strategy to get down to 8 *bands* would be to use large chunks and normalize the values. Then you could break the values up into eight segments and get the sum of each segments.  I think this is valid - maybe only for the power spectral density. [sklearn.preprocessing.normalize](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

```
w = sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(Pxx[1:,:], norm = 'l1', axis = 0)
```

---

But then again, I just made all that up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the `scipy.io.wavfile.read` function that @wwii mentions in his answer, but it seems that his suggestion is the way to go to handle the signal loading. However, I just wanted to comment on the fourier transform.

What I imagine that you intend to do with your LED setup is to change each of the LED's brightnesses according to the power of the spectra in each of the 8 frequency bands that you intend to use. Thus, what I understood that you need, is to compute in some way the power as time goes by. The first complication is "how to compute the spectral power?"

The best way to do this is with the `numpy.fft.rfft`, which computes the fourier transform for signals that only have real numbers (not complex numbers). On the other hand, the function `numpy.fft.fft` is a general purpose function that can compute the fast fourier transform for signals with complex numbers. The conceptual difference is that `numpy.fft.fft` can be used to study travelling waves and their propagation direction. This is seen because the returned amplitudes correspond to [positive or negative frequencies](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html#numpy.fft.fftfreq) that indicate how the wave travels. `numpy.fft.rfft` yields the amplitude for real-valued frequencies as seen in `numpy.fft.rfftfreq`, which is what you need.

The last issue is to choose appropriate frequency bands in which to compute the spectral power. The human ear has a huge frequency response range and the width of each band will vary very much, with the low frequency band being very narrow and the high frequency band being very wide. Googling around, I found [this](http://www.teachmeaudio.com/mixing/techniques/audio-spectrum) nice resource that defines 7 relevant frequency bands

1. Sub-bass: 20 to 60 Hz
2. Bass: 60 to 250 Hz
3. Low midrange: 250 to 500 Hz
4. Midrange: 500 Hz to 2 kHz
5. Upper midrange: 2 to 4 kHz
6. Presence: 4 to 6 kHz
7. Brilliance: 6 to 20 kHz

I would suggest to use these bands, but split the upper midrange into 2-3 kHz and 3-4kHz. That way you'll be able to use your 8 LED setup. I'm uploading an updated pitch function for you to use

```
wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
CHUNK = 1024
RATE = wf.getframerate()
DT = 1./float(RATE)   # time between two successive audio frames
FFT_FREQS = numpy.fft.nfftfreq(CHUNCK,DT)
FFT_FREQS_INDS = -numpy.ones_like(FFT_FREQS)
bands_bounds = [[20,60],      # Sub-bass
                [60,250],     # Bass
                [250,500],    # Low midrange
                [500,2000],   # Midrange
                [2000,3000],  # Upper midrange 0
                [3000,4000],  # Upper midrange 1
                [4000,6000],  # Presence
                [6000,20000]] # Brilliance

for f_ind,freq in enumerate(FFT_FREQS):
    for led_ind,bounds in enumerate(bands_bounds):
        if freq<bounds[1] and freq>=bounds[0]:
            FFT_FREQS_INDS[ind] = led_ind

# Returns the spectral power in each of the 8 bands assigned to the LEDs
def pitch(signal):
    # CONSIDER SWITCHING TO scipy.io.wavfile.read TO GET SIGNAL
    signal = numpy.fromstring(signal, 'Int16');
    amplitude = numpy.fft.rfft(signal.astype(numpy.float))
    power = [np.sum(np.abs(amplitude[FFT_FREQS_INDS==led_ind])**2) for led_ind in range(len(bands_bounds))]
    return power
```

The first part of the code computes the fft frequencies and constructs the array `FFT_FREQS_INDS` that indicates to which of the 8 frequency bands the fft frequency corresponds to. Then, in `pitch` the power of the spectra in each of the bands is computed. Of course, this can be optimized but I tried to make the code self-explanatory.

Comment: I get this error: `if freq<bounds[1] and freq>=bounds[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @catfish ups! I had a typo in the bounds list. I had written `-` instead of `,`